# Why does the selenium send keys function not always work for my code?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

The following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


def github_login(username, password, github_username):
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    browser.get('https://github.com')

    browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/header/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/a').click()

    username_box = browser.find_element(By.ID, 'login_field')
    username_box.send_keys(username + Keys.RETURN)

    password_box = browser.find_element(By.ID, 'password')
    password_box.send_keys(password + Keys.RETURN)

    browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/header/div[7]/details/summary/img').click()
    browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/header/div[7]/details/details-menu/a[1]').click

    if browser.current_url == 'https://github.com/' + str(github_username):
        print('successfully loged in to github')
        return 'successfull login'
    else:
        print('Login failed')
        return 'login failed'


login = github_login(username='code7g', password='randompassword', github_username='Code7G')
```

executes correctly only 1/10 time.

From line 0 to 10:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


def github_login(username, password, github_username):
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    browser.get('https://github.com')

    browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[1]/header/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/a').click()
```

the browser does everything correctly 100% of the time.

But when it comes to the send keys function:

```
username_box = browser.find_element(By.ID, 'login_field')
username_box.send_keys(username + Keys.RETURN)

password_box = browser.find_element(By.ID, 'password')
password_box.send_keys(password + Keys.RETURN)
```

the browser does not send the keys 90% of the time, sometimes it does and I don't know why.
Does this have to do something with the GitHub login system or with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues I can point here:

1. Looks like you are missing delays.
   You should wait for elements to be clickable or visible before clicking them or sending them texts. `WebDriverWait` `expected_conditions` explicit conditions should be used for that.
2. You should improve your locators. Absolute XPaths are extremely unreliable and fragile.
3. No need to send `Keys.RETURN` with username. Also, I'd prefer clicking "Sing in" button rather than sending `Keys.RETURN` with password, but if it works - no problem :)
   This should work better:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def github_login(username, password, github_username):
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
    browser.get('https://github.com')
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@href='/login']"))).click()
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "login_field"))).send_keys(username)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "password"))).send_keys(password)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='commit']"))).click()
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "summary .avatar-small"))).click()
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(.,'Your profile')]"))).click()
```